# Plot against time of format "hh:mm:ss" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of time-indexed data, that I have to plot with MATLAB.

The current format of the time is as follows

```
23:55:42,-147928.686833054
23:55:43,-147928.404621219
23:55:44,-147928.219419702
23:55:45,-147928.395802099
23:55:46,-147928.492812417
23:55:47,-147928.413440339
23:55:48,-147928.386982979
```

I simply wish to plot the second column, the values, against the first column, the time.

I can of course take the first time point as 0, and next as 1, ..., and so on. However, I wish to stick with the original timing.

How may I deal with this type of time handily?

Answer (score 2):

Convert your time values using [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html).  Create an X-Y plot in the usual way.  And ask for time-formatted labels with

```
datetick('x', 13)
```

For example:

```
plot(datenum(a(:,1)), a(:,2));
datetick('x', 13)
```

Comment: I cannot perform datenum on my x values, who is a 1*34267 cell. Should I convert it into array and then datenum it?

Comment: @FarticlePilter: Try `cellfun(@datenum, x)`

Comment: datenum('1:59:58', 'HH:MM:SS') and datenum('21:59:58', 'HH:MM:SS') both return me 7.3560e+05, which is apparently incorrect.

Comment: @FarticlePilter: Seems ok to me.  Those numbers are in days, so the difference of 20 hours (5/6 of a day) isn't being shown.  But it is there.  If you don't like that MATLAB is attaching today's date, use `mod(datenum('1:59:58', 'HH:MM:SS'), 1)` which throws away the date part and keeps just the time.

Comment: It works now. Thank you so much! However, converting it into day makes the plot more counterintuitive to make sense. Is there any way that I can keep the time still shown as hh:mm:ss on x-axis?

Comment: @FarticlePilter: That's exactly what the `dateaxis` command in my answer will do.

Comment: But I encounter `Undefined function 'dateaxis' for
input arguments of type 'char'.` for that line.

Comment: @FarticlePilter: Sorry! The command is `datetick`. MATLAB confused me because there is a toolbox with a `dateaxis` command which does the same thing. But `datetick` is what I normally use and you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the property "XTickLabel" after plotting.

You can use it with a cell of strings of your data:

```
plot(second-column-values)
Times={'23:55:42','23:55:43',...}     
set(gca,'XTickLabel',Times)
```

Comment: This won't preserve the time intervals.

Comment: You right. Didn't know about the option in your answer. Shoult be better, if works :)